# MySQL can show tables but cannot access data (errno: 13 - Permission denied)

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, permissions, bitnami

I am fixing a server that uses Bitnami to run a WordPress site. I did not set up the server – it ran out of memory and crashed.

I was able to restart MySQL through the bitnami ctlscript, and I am able to access the MySQL CLI, but I  **cannot execute any queries that return data INSIDE the tables**.

**The following commands all work**, and generate the expected output:

- show databases;
- use database 'x';
- show tables;

As soon as I try to **view table data** (SELECT * FROM ...), **this error shows up**:

2019-01-15T18:25:19.507808Z 233 [ERROR] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld.bin: Can't find file: './bitnami_wordpress/wp_options.frm' (errno: 13 - Permission denied)

**What I've tried:**

- Database file permissions. All data (specifically the
  wp_tablename.frm files) is chowned by mysql:mysql
- I confirmed this by changing permissions to my server user, restarting and trying to access mysql again, but the commands above, which already worked, broke, so I changed it back.
- Reboots of all sorts. Bitnami, server, etc.
- Selinux. I am 95% sure it is not running on this server (all commands
  that check its status / install info return 'use apt-get    to
  install    this package) or something like that.

Please help! This site is in production!

Comment: Is it a bitnami mysql server? Are you ok to try a different server?

Comment: Yes, bitnami seems to run apache, mysql, and php-fpm.Unfortunately I'd much rather work it out with this – my job is just to restore the server as-is and I have no idea what other complications would arise from that :/

Comment: If it was in production and it needs to be restored ASAP, I was thinking if you can temporarily move it to a different server like say ubuntu or even RDS free tier until this is resolved.

Comment: Valid, but that is a last-ditch effort for me, hoping this gets resolved as I feel very close.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here, can you check the permissions of the /opt/bitnami/mysql/data folder? Maybe there is something wrong with the permissions there and the mysql user can't write in its subfolders. Can you also check the mysqld.log file (/opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log) in case there is any other error message there?

Comment: Hey Jota, thank you for the recommendations – I confirmed that the folder had the proper permissions, and the mysql log was just a ton of the same error message above (permission denied). I actually zipped the folder and downloaded the files and tried to query them on my local machine with the same results. I believe those files are just corrupted. I don't know how that happened but it's an issue beyond the scope of bitnami. Thanks though :)